# Remove keys in hash not in array

Tags: ruby, hash

I can't find a way to remove keys from a hash that are not in a given array of key names. I read that I can use `except` or `slice`, but how can I feed them a list of the key names I want to keep?  So for example, if I had this hash:

```
entry = {:title=>"casablanca", :media=>"dvd", :localeLanguage=>"en", :imdb=>"", :freebase=>"", :originalTitle => 'casablanca', :season=> '1', :episode => '3'}
```

and I only wanted to keep, say, `:title`, `:media` and `:localeLanguage`, how could I keep only those values whose key names I specify?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I'd use `keep_if` (requires 1.9.2).

```
keepers = [:title, :media, :localeLanguage]

entry.keep_if {|k,_| keepers.include? k }

#=> {:title=>"casablanca", :media=>"dvd", :localeLanguage=>"en"}
```

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks Thomas, this is great. I didn't know about `.keep_if`. Is this only Ruby 1.9.x? Ah. I see you edited it to clarify that. Thanks.

Comment: In this case, it reads well. Some people [don't like it](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2247352).

Answer (score 26):

In Rails 4+, use [slice](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice):

```
entry = {:title=>"casablanca", :media=>"dvd", :localeLanguage=>"en", :imdb=>"", :freebase=>"", :originalTitle => 'casablanca', :season=> '1', :episode => '3'}
keepers = [:title, :media, :localeLanguage]

entry.slice(*keepers)
# => {:title=>"casablanca", :media=>"dvd", :localeLanguage=>"en"}
```

Shorter version (with same result):

```
entry.slice(*%i(title media localeLanguage))
```

Use [slice!](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/slice!) to modify your hash in-place.

Answer (score 4):

In Ruby 1.9.3:

```
entry = entry.select do |key, value|
  [:title, :media, :localeLanguage].include?(key)
end
p entry
# => {:title=>"casablanca", :media=>"dvd", :localeLanguage=>"en"}
```

In Ruby 1.8.7, Hash#select returns an array of arrays, so use Hash[] to turn that array into a hash:

```
entry = Hash[
  entry.select do |key, value|
    [:title, :media, :localeLanguage].include?(key)
  end
]
# => {:media=>"dvd", :localeLanguage=>"en", :title=>"casablanca"}
```

The difference in order is because, in Ruby 1.8.7, Hashes are unordered.

Comment: Thanks for putting solutions for both 1.9.3 and 1.8.7. Quite useful since I might have to convert the code to 1.8.7 at some point (hopefully not!)